# How to use varargs with __stdcall without the compiler corrupting the stack

Tags: c++, c, visual-c++, icc

I've encountered the problem with MSVC and ICC:

I need to use a varadic arguments with an stdcall calling convention, but the compiler ignores it for varadic functions and corrupts the stack.

Easy way to fix this would be to just take the number of arguments as one of the arguments and offset `ESP` before it's corrupted, but in this case I don't need the number of args for the context of the function so would rather avoid it if possible.

Does somebody know if there's a way to do this?

Comment: By default you can't. When using `stdcall` the _callee_ is responsible for cleaning up the stack. Since the _callee_ doens't know the number of arguments or how much stack space the arguments take up it cannot logically clean up the stack without being provided additional information. What you are trying to do is not a good idea and any attempt to make it work will likely be a lot more effort than it is worth. This sounds like an XY problem and you should really rethink what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: @CaptainObvlious This is not a traditional function.  And really the nicest solution is to do what im asking (if it's possible). But see my response to John's answer; it explains a bit more.

Answer (score 1):

As per the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zxk0tw93.aspx):

> The callee cleans the stack, so the compiler makes vararg functions `__cdecl`.

Given this, I'm not sure how you expect to proceed.  If `stdcall` requires the callee to clean the stack, but in vararg functions the callee cannot know what's on the stack at compile-time, how would it work?  Would you expect the `stdarg` `va_list` macros to manipulate the call frame?  I don't think that's how Microsoft sees it, so what you're asking doesn't seem possible, at least not by writing C using the Microsoft compiler.

Comment: In 99% of instances it would be rediculous to try and this, I agree. Unfortunately in my function it does clean the stack up properly, but I can't *not* clean up the stack becasue it's not my code that's doing it.

Comment: @Nowayz Don't be shy, it's ridiculous 100% of the time.

Comment: @CaptainObvlious Not this time :)  The function is proxy calling into a WINAPI(stdcall) which cleans the stack on its own, then doing a jmp back to the cached retn pointer since it had to be shuffled off the top of the stack.  Meaning the stack has a 100% garuntee of being cleaned properly every time, but the compiler still tries to do it.

Comment: @Nowayz: I don't know why you're trying to fight it. You know what the calling conventions are and what is required for them. This magic function you talk about is not following any conventions and is making up its own, it's not stdcall... If you wish to operate with this function, you have to follow whatever convention it is using, even if this means having to write out your own prologue/epilogue.

Comment: @JeffMercado That's the reason I'm asking this question - good observations though.  (*I will presumably have to write my own epilogue in this case though, I just wanted to avoid it*)

Comment: @Nowayz: how do you *actually* call the function, in practice?  Do you always call it with one specific count of parameters of specific types?  And what language do you actually call from: C or C++?  And on what target ISA?  x86?  amd64?

Comment: @Nowayz: The Win32 API uses `__stdcall` for everything, except for `wsprintf()` which requires `__cdecl`. Your proxy should be using `__stdcall` as well. It sounds like you are trying to make a `__cdecl` proxy act like it were `__stdcall`, and that is simply not going to work. I agree with CaptainOblivious, this is an XY problem. You are chasing the wrong solution. Post the code you are having trouble with, and maybe someone can tell you how to fix it properly.

Comment: @RemyLebeau It's not an XY problem, and even if it were you should focus on the question for its own sake rather than skirt it because you assume incompetence.  I've solved this myself by just taking argc and offsetting esp register, as I suggested in my original question

Comment: @Nowayz: so you're not on amd64/x86_64 I guess?  Because AFAIK, MSVC does not support inline assembly there.  That's why I asked yesterday what ISA you're using.

Comment: @JohnZwinck I use the intel compiler for inline assembly when compiling to AMD64 arch, but in this case I was writing the code for IA-32.  (Though I did have plans to write implementation for both)